# Sparql example for the book "learning Sparql" doesn't work

Tags: sparql

I m a newbie to Sparql and try to understand it through studying a book called learning Sparql by  DuCharme. Unfortunately an example doesn't seem to work and I don't get problem.
As requested in the book I type this in at https://dbpedia.org/snorql/

```
PREFIX d: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?artistName ?albumName

WHERE  
{
  ?album  d:producer :Timbaland .
  ?album  d:musicalArtist ?artist .
  ?album rdfs:label ?albumName .
  ?artist rdfs:label ?artistName .
}
```

Thank you for any help and any hint on how to debug sparql queries.

Comment: change `d:musicalArtist` to `d:artist`

Comment: you might also be interested in using language filters: `filter(langmatches(lang(?albumName),"en"))
  filter(langmatches(lang(?artistName),"en"))`

Comment: thank you very much! yes the filters make sense - it's also the next step in the book

Comment: just to clarify, the book might be outdated resp. DBpedia might have changed their data model. I'd also suggest to use the more modern web UI at https://dbpedia.org/sparql/

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice - I do so.